# how to use create and write function in openerp module development?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have been creating a custom openerp-7 module. I have created 2 forms , a parent and a child form. I am calling the child form from parent form through a button . There are 2 fields in child form and I want to save the field data to my parent form . What function should I use to save my data to parent window.

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you, you have a child form/model with fields and you want to save the value of a couple of fields onto the parent model?

In this case, you would override the create and write methods like this:

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context = None):
   res = super(MyChildClass, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context = context)
   if 'child_field' in values:
      for child_item in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context = context):
          self.pool.get('my.parent.model').write(cr, uid, [child_item.parent_id.id], {'parent_field': values['child_field'],}, context = context) 

   return res
```

Going from memory here but I think this is right.  Note you only want to do the write to the parent if they are changing the child field.  The create is much the same except you don't get a list of ids for the child items being written.

Comment: can you explain me a little about what is ' child_field ' and 'parent_field'  here , and again may I post my project ? because there is no parent field , until and unless someone set the value on child form and hit button . When he create a field , only then there will appear a field on parent form